# Find And Edit Line in File

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

If some file contains a line:

```
...
OPTION=“—option1 —option2 param —option3 —option4”
...
```

What would be the best combination of utilities
to:

- Find that line in the file (assume it’s the only line with the string ‘OPTION’
- append to the option string so it’s now:

  ```
  OPTION=“—option1 —option2 param —option3 —option4”
  ```

Comment: (1) Did you do any research?  What did you learn?   (2) What’s the difference between your before and after?

Answer (score 1):

With the venerable ed:

```
ed file <<<EOF
/OPTION/a
-option5
.
wq
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/\(OPTION=\“—option1 —option2 param —option3 —option4\)\"/\1 -option5\"/
```

`\(` puts the pattern into a register that is recalled by `\1` for substitution.  Notice `\"` where you have to escape `"` with a backslash.

If you are searching for the pattern starting with `OPTION`, you can use

```
sed 's/\(OPTION=.*\)\"/\1 -option5\"/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/(OPTION=".*)"/$1  —option5"/g' file.txt
```

- manuals; [perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html), [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)
- -p is per line loop
- -i is inline
- -e is expression ([regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html))